# improving OCR text detection/segmentation in natural images using OpenCV

Tags: python, c++, opencv, ocr, tesseract

I'm working on an OCR text detection and recognition problem where after trying out [Text Scene Detection and Recognition with OpenCV 3](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/text/doc/erfilter.html) using Opencv and Tesseract libraries on some images, I made some remarks (manually after checking detection image output, segmentation output and recognition output images) and I'm looking for how to improve the result by making changes in the code.

First the images are black-white (mostly gray and the text is whether black or white) in origin and the text can be a combination of numerical and alphabetical characters.

1 - When the text color intensity is not too different from the background one, no text is detected.

2- When the image contain for example "63H" it's correctly detected, but if there is more space between (e.g: "63 H") it's not detected at all.

3-When different text regions are not perfectly aligned (different picture angle than another correct text detection of the same form) one part of the text is detected, the other is not (e.g text = 12548   58A. 12548 is part one. 58A is part2).

I tried to analyze results and thought that probably the reason behind these remarks is in ERGrouping phase ('m using the [Exhaustive Search algorithm grouping algorithm](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~neumalu1/icdar2011_article.pdf). grouping arbitrary oriented text gives me worse results). If so how to improve it?

Can anyone help me better understand the remarks causes? (Unfortunately, I cannot share images because they are confidential)

What modification on classifier parameters  can I do in order to improve the result (I'm using default classifiers files provided by opencv)?

```
createERFilterNM1(const Ptr<ERFilter::Callback>& cb, int thresholdDelta=1, float minArea=0.00025, float maxArea=0.13, float minProbability=0.4, bool nonMaxSuppression=true, float minProbabilityDiff=0.1 )
```

What other methods can I try? (Options are open about libraries and language(Python/C++). 
    // TextRecognition.cpp : définit le point d'entrée pour l'application console.
    //
    /*
     * textdetection.cpp
     *

```
 */

#include "opencv2/text.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/utility.hpp"
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <fstream>

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace cv::text;

//Calculate edit distance between two words
size_t edit_distance(const string& A, const string& B);
size_t min(size_t x, size_t y, size_t z);
bool   isRepetitive(const string& s);
bool   sort_by_lenght(const string &a, const string &b);
//Draw ER's in an image via floodFill
void   er_draw(vector<Mat> &channels, vector<vector<ERStat> > &regions, vector<Vec2i> group, Mat& segmentation);

//Perform text detection and recognition and evaluate results using edit distance
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    cout << endl << argv[0] << endl << endl;
    cout << "Text Detection and Recognition: " << endl;
    cout << "algorithm described in:" << endl;
    cout << "Real-Time Scene Text Localization and Recognition" << endl << endl;

    Mat image;
    // image  = imread("C:\\scene-text-recognition\\scenetext01.jpg");

     if(argc>1)
        image  = imread(argv[1]);
    else
    {
        cout << "    Usage: " << argv[0] << " <input_image> [<gt_word1> ... <gt_wordN>]" << endl;
        return(0);
    }


    cout << "IMG_W=" << image.cols << endl;
    cout << "IMG_H=" << image.rows << endl;


    /*Text Detection*/

    // Extract channels to be processed individually
    vector<Mat> channels;

    Mat grey;
    cvtColor(image,grey,COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

    // Notice here we are only using grey channel, see textdetection.cpp for example with more channels
    channels.push_back(grey);
    channels.push_back(255-grey);

    double t_d = (double)getTickCount();
    // Create ERFilter objects with the 1st and 2nd stage default classifiers
    //createERFilterNM1(const Ptr<ERFilter::Callback>& cb, int thresholdDelta=1, float minArea=0.00025, float maxArea=0.13, float minProbability=0.4, bool nonMaxSuppression=true, float minProbabilityDiff=0.1 )
    Ptr<ERFilter> er_filter1 = createERFilterNM1(loadClassifierNM1("trained_classifierNM1.xml"),8,0.00015f,0.13f,0.2f,true,0.2f);
    Ptr<ERFilter> er_filter2 = createERFilterNM2(loadClassifierNM2("trained_classifierNM2.xml"),0.5);

    vector<vector<ERStat> > regions(channels.size());
    // Apply the default cascade classifier to each independent channel (could be done in parallel)
    for (int c=0; c<(int)channels.size(); c++)
    {
        er_filter1->run(channels[c], regions[c]);
        er_filter2->run(channels[c], regions[c]);
    }
    cout << "TIME_REGION_DETECTION = " << ((double)getTickCount() - t_d)*1000/getTickFrequency() << endl;

    Mat out_img_decomposition= Mat::zeros(image.rows+2, image.cols+2, CV_8UC1);
    vector<Vec2i> tmp_group;
    for (int i=0; i<(int)regions.size(); i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<(int)regions[i].size();j++)
        {
            tmp_group.push_back(Vec2i(i,j));
        }
        Mat tmp= Mat::zeros(image.rows+2, image.cols+2, CV_8UC1);
        er_draw(channels, regions, tmp_group, tmp);
        if (i > 0)
            tmp = tmp / 2;
        out_img_decomposition = out_img_decomposition | tmp;
        tmp_group.clear();
    }

    double t_g = (double)getTickCount();
    // Detect character groups
    vector< vector<Vec2i> > nm_region_groups;
    vector<Rect> nm_boxes;
     erGrouping(image, channels, regions, nm_region_groups, nm_boxes,ERGROUPING_ORIENTATION_HORIZ);
    //erGrouping(image, channels, regions, nm_region_groups, nm_boxes,ERGROUPING_ORIENTATION_ANY,"trained_classifier_erGrouping.xml",0.5);
    cout << "TIME_GROUPING = " << ((double)getTickCount() - t_g)*1000/getTickFrequency() << endl;
```